# Regarding the type 2 or 3 ANOVA, does the analysis via model reduction correspond to LRT and via contrasts - to Wald approach?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, likelihood-ratio, wald-test

I noticed, that in R we can obtain type 2 and type 3 ANOVA in many ways in unbalanced designs:

For example, for type-2

- car::Anova(...type=2),
- by running anova() over a sequence of models with swapped order variables and by taking the last item
- when no interaction - by running drop1()

I learned, that car::Anova compares contrasts (thus, means), while drop1 or anova() compares models, either by variance or deviance or again, Wald's approach.

This confuses me a little. I saw once a post describing the differences between Wald's, LRT and score tests. Does car::Anova() use the Wald's approach, and the anova() or drop1 use the likelihood ratio, as long as working with likelihood- based methods? And what, if they don't? For example, anova() is defined for the GEE estimation, which definitely doesn't support LRT, so only Wald's approach is used, so I guess it must compare just coefficients jointly.

Am I right, that comparing models by checking the deviance is the LR testing, while jointly testing model coefficients is the Wald's approach?